# PHP MYSQL displaying picture link from dB

Tags: php, html, image, imageurl

Hey all I have a table caleld Box1, with a simple structure of:  id(increment,primary) imageurl, link.

What I am looking to do, is on my site in the HTML file, display the imageurl into a imgsrc, so  that the Image URL loads the image when going to the site

I cannot find specifically what I am looking for online and know I must be close somewhere,  this is what I have so far in my coding for my .php file.... thanks.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","data","data");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }else {

        mysql_select_db("database1", $con);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Box1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['image'];

// NEXT STEP IS TO DISPLAY THE  the IMAGE  EXAMPLE: '<img src code<?php echo 'image'; ?>' >
        }
    }

 mysql_close($con)
?>
```

if you could guide me to an exmaple of how to do this, that would be amazing, im so confused how one would implement  HTML with PHP, thanks!!

Comment: Your code looks ok, except you are echoing $row['image'] instead of $row['imageurl'] Note that the array keys for $row will be the names of the fields in your query. In simplistic terms, PHP runs on the server and speaks to the client (your browser). If your script does not "say it out loud" (echo, var_dump etc), then the client won't hear it. To construct the html, the script must dictate it from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

... connect to DB ...
$sql = "SELECT imgurl FROM Box1 WHERE id=XXX";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $row['imgurl'] ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is helpful to become familiar with this operator for large chunks of html

```
echo <<<YOUR_TOKEN_NAME
     <img src="$row['imgurl']" />
      ...misc html and php vars intermixed 
YOUR_TOKEN_NAME;
```

Comment: You should mention that this is called a heredoc, and is documented at http://php.net/heredoc  otherwise it's just some goofy looking operator and means nothing to the unenlightened.